# How to get date from inside of span - while not available in beautifulsoup object?

Tags: python, date, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been scraping the https://www.oddsportal.com/ website using `bs4` and `requests`.

In order to scrape out the dates of the matches, I have used the following code.

`dates_list = soup_league.tbody.find_all('th',{'class': 'first2 tl'})`

This returns a list like,

```
 <th class="first2 tl" colspan="3"><span class="datet t1642016700-2-0-0-1"></span></th>,
 <th class="first2 tl" colspan="3"><span class="datet t1642249800-2-0-0-1"></span></th>,
 <th class="first2 tl" colspan="3"><span class="datet t1642334400-2-0-0-1"></span></th>,
 <th class="first2 tl" colspan="3"><span class="datet t1642535100-2-0-0-1"></span></th>,
 <th class="first2 tl" colspan="3"><span class="datet t1642622400-2-0-0-1"></span></th>,
 <th class="first2 tl" colspan="3"><span class="datet t1642854600-2-0-0-1"></span></th>,
 <th class="first2 tl" colspan="3"><span class="datet t1643053500-2-0-0-1"></span></th>]
```

Here the date in element is no more available. But the actual code in browser contains the date element inside the span tag as

`<span class="datet t1641544200-2-0-0-1">07 Jan 2022</span>`

Why is this behaving like this? Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** *Always look in your soup first - therein lies the truth. The content can always be slightly to extremely different from the view in the development tools.*

#### What happens?

Content is not provided static it is provided dynamically, so with `requests` you won't handle it that way, it do not support rendering of javascript.

#### How to fix?

1. Best way would be to search for an alternativ or use an api.
2. Use `selenium` to grab the rendered html and process it with `beautifulsoup`
3. If it is only this part you have to achieve, grab the timestamp from class and transform it via `datetime`

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
url='https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for d in soup.select('#tournamentTable span.datet'):
    ts = int(d['class'][-1].split('-')[0][1:])
    print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%d %b %Y'))
```

#### Output

```
11 Jan 2022
12 Jan 2022
14 Jan 2022
15 Jan 2022
16 Jan 2022
21 Jan 2022
22 Jan 2022
23 Jan 2022
```

Comment: But the output differs from what is in the UI right?

Comment: You can also format the output with [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) edited the example.

Comment: How can a Selenium bot be used to scrape out all the HTML code?

Comment: Keeping focus clear on the answered question - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), that focus just on scraping with  selenium approach. Would be great - We will notice and and answer this as well. Thanks